# How do you preserve message order when consuming messages from ActiveMQ?

Tags: .net, activemq-classic

I have a .NET service that uses the ActiveMQ client.  I have implemented a MessageListener with a transacted connection to consume the messages.

Occasionally, I get messages in a different order in which they were put onto the queue.

Was it wrong to use a MessageListner?  Is there a way to preserve the message order?

FYI: There is one producer putting messages on the queue and one consumer pulling messages off the queue.

Comment: Please see this thread for a little more background on the issue  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/269363/activemq-net-client-locks-up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More Info:  The server I call is third party and I have no control over what messages it sends.  I do know, based on the message ID's that they are put on in the right order. Also, in this system there is a difference between ACK and Acknowledge.  The ACK is received when my original message is put on the the "outbound" queue.  I then monitor an "inbound" queue for responses.  I usually get an "Acknowledge" followed by a "Pass" or a "Fail".  The correlation ID for these messages is the message ID from the ACK.

I had originally used a message listener and responded to an OnMessge event.  I abandoned this approach after realizing that, using this method, messages are delivered asynchronously and therefore in no particular order.  So, I changed my code to poll using a timer (System.Threading.Timer) to call consumer.Receive() and get one message at a time.  This works the way I want.

I open the consumer once when the service starts and I continuously poll for messages.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have to do anything to maintain the order; that's one of the things that a message queue does for you.  I would think that if you have a single consumer listening to the queue, and it is processing messages out of order, then you have either found a bug or the messages aren't enqueued in the order you think they are.

Also, there's [this question](http://activemq.apache.org/how-do-i-preserve-order-of-messages.html) from the [ActiveMQ FAQ](http://activemq.apache.org/faq.html) that might help.

**Edit:** From reading the comments on [duffymo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426532/how-to-you-preserve-message-order-when-consuming-messages-from-activemq#426613), it looks like you're overengineering a bit.  In general, a message queue like ActiveMQ, MQ Series, joram, etc. have two characteristics: they deliver messages in the same order in which they are enqueued, and they guarantee message delivery.  Sending a separate ACK message is redundant; it's a bit like committing a database transaction, then querying the same information back to double-check that the database actually stored it.

Having said that, is your server multithreaded?  If so it may possible for it to enqueue the response **before** it enqueues the ACK.

Answer (score 0):

Why is message order important?  A MessageListener shouldn't have to care.

If you need a correlation ID to match a response with a particular request, that's another matter.  Is that what you mean?

Comment: A message is sent to a server via queue and the server sends back responses to that message on another queue.  I get 2 responses, first a message that says "Acknowledge" then one that says "Pass" (or Fail). The all have the same Correlation ID.  Sometimes I get the "Acknowledge" message last.

Comment: bad design, IMO.  The ACK sounds like it should be synchronous, nothing more than "We got your request and it will be processed."  I'd have a synch processor like a servlet do that and put the request on the queue.  Then it's just one req/res pair, and the correlation ID means something.

Answer (score 0):

Everything Jason just said. A few other things to be careful of. You are keeping the consumer open for lots of messages right? You're not creating a consumer for a few messages then closing it? Only closing a consumer causes messages associated with a consumer to be put back onto a queue which can break order.

Is it related to rollbacks? (Are you rolling back any transactions?).

Finally, you can always ensure order by using a [Resequencer](http://activemq.apache.org/camel/resequencer.html) to reorder things for you.